# Laravel return collection with relation and with calculation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a laravel application which has a model Client.

A client has many addresses, many jobs and many transactions.

I've the following relations on my client model:

```
public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job','client_id');
    }

public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address','client_id');
    }

public function Fees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction','client_id');
    }
```

I then have another function on that model which calculates the value

```
public function balance() 
    {
        return $this->Fees()->where('status',2)->sum('gross');
    }
```

I'm trying to return a list of all clients along with their addresses, jobs and the balance of each client.

I've tried the following:

```
 $customers = $user->clients()->with('balance')->with('jobs')->with('addresses')->get();
```

I get the following error

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string

This will no doubt be the eagerloading and the fact the balance() isn't a collection but I'm wondering how I would achieve the same result without having to loop through to build an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions in with functions as follows

```
$customers = $user->clients()
                  ->with(['jobs', 'addresses'])
                  ->with(['Fees'=> function($query){
                       $query->selectRaw('sum(fees_table_name.gross) as gross')
                             ->where('status',2);

                   }])
                   ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for that I've tried but this returns all the Fees rather than the sum value?

Comment: The new update is supposed to work. It is based on this link. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-use-sumcolumn-from-relation-in-where-clause-and-orderby-it